# How can set show multiplicity option to association shape (Visio) C#, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio, shapesheet

How can I turn on the show multiplicity option to association shape and access 4 position in visio using c# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.

Comment: I guess there is no way to do that. Visio provides no API for the ER or UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User.ShowMulti` cell in the Association shape's [ShapeSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/about-the-shapesheet-spreadsheet) controls the multiplicity option. You can set it thought Visio's API like this:

```
shape.get_Cells("User.ShowMulti").Formula = "TRUE"
```

The 4 access positions are sub-shapes in the association shape. The order in the Shapes collection should be fixed so you can do something like this:

```
shape.Shapes[1].Text = "Top Left";
shape.Shapes[2].Text = "Bottom Left";
shape.Shapes[3].Text = "Top Right";
shape.Shapes[4].Text = "Bottom Right";
```

Comment: it's working fine thanks can you suggest me how can  we change the text of that 4 position text.

Comment: @Priya I updated the answer to address the access position shapes.

Comment: It's working, @HappyMoose thanks.